# Find all constraints that will be violated by record deletion

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have a Member table, which records are used in multiple places(more than 10 tables). All referenced with constraints.

So far I get to see the first place where SQL engine has bumped into a constraint(from error message 547 when I'm trying to delete the record). It would be really handy to find out all the places where the record that I'm trying to delete is used.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Is UNION a possible solution?

Comment: @Bulat how do you want me to use UNION?

Comment: @IgorShch you can just union all the tables in question and check if you have any results for specific MemberId. Also if you can delete the member that has say address record, then you can use ON DELETE CASCADE for addresses table, and only check tables that are important, say Orders.

Comment: @Bulat thanks for the reply. 
The union thing will be just too hard to code. 

And I do not want to use CASCADE option. I like my constraints:))

Comment: @IgorShch If you like your constraints, then your application must delete records in specific order, so FKs are not violated. Otherwise Long Union is the best option. You probably can use Sys tables to code up a reusable SQL generator for that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL database management systems generally don't expose that capability. For tables that are referenced by hundreds of foreign keys, identifying and returning every possible  violation would be much more costly than returning just the first one.

You *could* write a stored procedure that

- reads the system tables for foreign key constraints,
- ignores the FK constraints that have `on delete cascade`,
- checks every one of those referencing tables for FK values that will prevent deleting rows, and
- return those table names (or constraint names, or table and column names, or table names and what kind of action is causing the failure--whatever).

But it sounds like a lot of work for what you get. There might be better ways to solve this kind of problem. (Better than trying to find all the possible FK constraint failures.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Catcall.

Even though my database is big, I still know where what referenced to.. I was more looking to derive info about where this exact value is used. 

Thank you very much, anyway.

Comment: Almost all the information you need is in the [information_schema views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179987.aspx). AFAIK, the only exception is determining the schema; use sys.objects for that.